# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required in spring+hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am doing spring + hibernate apllication. When I run the application on tomcat server I am getting some exception. Below is my code.

This is my bean config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

 <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>WEB-INF/database/db.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>Employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeBo" class="com.saggezza.employee.bo.impl.EmployeeBoImpl">
        <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.saggezza.employee.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

this is my dao class.

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements EmployeeDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public EmployeeDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionfactory){
        this.sessionFactory=sessionfactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Employee");

    }
}
```

Here another class employeeBo is calling the employeeDaoImpl.
when I run thisI am getting the below exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeBo' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/EmployeeBean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'employeeDao' while setting bean property 'employeeDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/EmployeeBean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
```

Can anybody help to resolve this. I have tried a lot and google it as well.But did get the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have two configuration files, you duplicates 'sessionFactory' definition. Remove one of the 'sessionFactory' definitions . You would have got duplicate bean definition exception before the IllegalArgumentException.

Edit: After your comment,

```
public class EmployeeDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements EmployeeDao {


public EmployeeDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionfactory){
    setSessionFactory(sessionfactory);
}

@Override
public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Employee");

}
}
```

or get rid of constructor in above code and inject  'sessionFactory' using setter injection.See `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.setSessionFactory(SessionFactory)`. I prefer later approach.

Comment: I have deleted the duplicate one but still getting that exception. And updated the question as well.

Comment: can you put the import statement of the `SessoinFactory` class?

Comment: is your Employee.hbm.xml located at WEB-INF/ folder?

Comment: @Adi I have changed my code to the above first method u have shown. But now I m getting this exception org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyExceptionInvalid property 'employeeDao' of bean class [com.saggezza.employee.bo.impl.EmployeeBoImpl]: Bean property 'employeeDao' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Did you mean 'employeedao'?

Comment: Is there a setter method 'setEmployeeDao' in EmployeeBoImpl? If so make it public. If it's not present add it.

Comment: @Adi the setter method is there and it is public only

Comment: sorry.I can't think of any other reason for this error. Can you post code of EmployeeBoImpl?

Comment: ya now i got. Thanks @Adi i have written the setter method but with a little mistake in case sense. now i corrected it. deploying fine in tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the type of `SessionFactory` you are injecting in `EmployeeDaoImpl` does not match with the type of the `SessionFactory` you used in the class.

Can you check it?

Comment: i am using org.hibernate.SessionFactoy in the dao class

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so must be solved now but still if someone comes across this problem. Following is solution.

You can use Hibernate DAO Support by extending HibernateDAOSupport class and overriding its afterPropertiesSet() method.

This method is called in HibernateDAO support and at that time since sessionFactory is null it is throwing this error. In your custom class you can set this property explicitly and then call the same method of Parent Class (i.e. HibernateDAOSupport's addProperties() method)

```
package com.techcielo.spring4.hibernate.template;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("hibernateTemplate")
public class Hibernate4CustomTemplate extends HibernateTemplate{

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        System.out.println("Setting SessionFactory");
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        super.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    System.out.println("Checking if properties set..."+this.sessionFactory);
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Following can be used for [sample](http://keyurj.blogspot.in/2014/01/jms-with-spring-4.html)!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fix it by using `Autowired` constructor with `EntityManagerFactory`. [Keyur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1884473/keyur) answer is correct

```
@Service
class EmployeeDaoImpl @Autowired constructor(
        factory: EntityManagerFactory
) : HibernateDaoSupport(), EmployeeDao {

    init {
        if (factory.unwrap(SessionFactory::class.java) == null) {
            throw NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory")
        }
        setSessionFactory(factory.unwrap(SessionFactory::class.java))
    }
    ...

}
```