# What am I supposed to put in Hibernate resources?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My situation is basic. Through this post, I want to get information how to properly describe sessionFactory. For the sake of clarity , I put code, so there are 3 files (2 classes, 1 interface):

### PLEASE SEE EDITED3 PART INSTEAD OF READING ALL.

**Stock.java**

```
package com.spring.hibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Stock implements Serializable {
    
    private long userId;
    private String userName;
    private int userAge;
    
    public void setUserId(long userId){
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    
    public long getUserId(){
        return userId;
    }
    
    public void setUserAge(int userAge){
        this.userAge = userAge;
    }
    
    public int getUserAge(){
        return userAge;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }
    
}
```

**StockDao.java**

```
package com.spring.hibernate;

public interface StockDao {
    
    void save(Stock stock);
    void update(Stock stock);
    void delete(Stock stock);
    Stock findById(long id);
}
```

**StockDaoImpl.java**

```
package com.spring.hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;


public class StockDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements StockDao{

    @Override
    public void save(Stock stock) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Stock stock) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Stock stock) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(stock);
    }

    @Override
    public Stock findById(long id) {
      List list = getHibernateTemplate().find("from userinf where id=?",id); // userinf is my table in database
      return (Stock)list.get(0);
    }
   
}
```

And now, I have came to the place where there is a problem. My Spring *xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">
    
    
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?"/>
    <property name="username" value="myinfuser"/>
    <property name="password" value="myinfuserpw"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="stockDaoImpl"
          class="com.spring.hibernate.StockDaoImpl"/>
    
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
     </property>
 
     <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
```

**What am I supposed to put in this area??**

```
    </list>
      </property>   
 
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

So, I do not know what kind of resource I need to put in area. Any help?

Thanks in advance

### EDITED:

So yeach..I got an exception by doing this:

**Stock.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.spring.hibernate.Stock" table="userinf">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="userName" type="String">
            <column name="name" length="12" not-null="true" unique="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="userAge" type="Integer">
            <column name="age" not-null="false" unique="false" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stockDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [database.properties.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.hibernate.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:115)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 12 more
```

And the area (which was empty before edit) is filled with:

```
    <property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
      <value>Stock.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
      </property>
```

By the way, my MainApp.java

```
ApplicationContext appContext = 
          new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("database.properties.xml");
 
        StockDao stockBo = (StockDao)appContext.getBean("stockDaoImpls");
 
        /** insert **/
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setUserName("Joe");
        stock.setUserAge(15);
        stockBo.save(stock);
 
        /** select **/
        Stock stock2 = stockBo.findById(1);
        System.out.println(stock2);
 
        System.out.println("Done");
```

Any idea how to fix it?

### EDITED2:

By your instructions, I added bean definition like this:

```
<bean id="stockDaoImpl"
      class="com.spring.hibernate.StockDaoImpl">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And edited my stockDaoImpl with adding constructor:

```
public StockDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionfactory){
    setSessionFactory(sessionfactory);
}
```

Now, My exception looks similar but with different causes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database.properties.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.class$(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

It seems that exception is getting bigger. How can I fix it?

## EDITED3:

One more time, I fixed above error, but now I have an exception which I cannot to solve:

```
aused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [database.properties.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/joran/spi/JoranException
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:189)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:152)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.class$(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Now, I really need your help about `joran.spi.JoranException`. How can it be solved?

Comment: I'd think you should to map your entities there.. you didn't find anything in google? Also your entity `Stock` you should map it with `Integer` rather than `int` the same with other primitive types

Comment: So I need to map my Stock variables with table columns?

Comment: You could use annotations too for that purpose, but you have to add entities like `Stock`to that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainApp.java file, you have mention bean "stockDaoImpls" but you have not added into your xml file.

```
  StockDao stockBo = (StockDao)appContext.getBean("stockDaoImpls");
```

Just add following bean into your xml file:

```
<bean id="stockDaoImpls" class="com.spring.hibernate.StockDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Hope it works for you..!!!!

Comment: but how can I do this if StockDaoImpl hasn't property like sessionFactory?

Comment: Check this link : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/ . Hope it can resolve your issue because your code are very similar to the above link.

Comment: But in real situation , i do not need BO to make a CRUD. Why it is using in this example?

Comment: Mostly we separate the Implementation logic from the DAO logic thats why you can see BO to make CRUD in above example and I check your error, it is NOClassFoundError. Seems like you have not added all jars file into your classpath.

Comment: Yes I have already done it, and now error is something about SINGLETON

Comment: I am doing it with Maven now, because of many jars (just confused). So in netbeans, when I describe dependencies, Maven will download automatically all jars? or do I need to start it work somehow (in eclipse it is a command like: mvn eclipse:eclipse) what about netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path to the [Hibernate XML files](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) describing the mapping between your `Stock` class and the database tables.

Comment: Please, see EDITED3 section

Answer (score 0):

`<property name="mappingResources">` Should contain your `*hbm.xml` Hibernate Mapping File, where your Stock class is mapped to database table. For more reference, visit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm

Comment: That's cool, but I have already done it, the result is in my edit part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045468/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-sessionfactory-or-hibernatetemplate-is-r

Comment: Thank you, I did it, it seems that now exception is bigger.